# Handing strings with binary data in it using java.nio

Tags: parsing, validation, scala, character-encoding, binary

I am having issues parsing text files that have illegal characters(binary markers) in them. An answer would be something as follows:

test.csv

```
^000000^id1,text1,text2,text3
```

Here the `^000000^` is a textual representation of illegal characters in the source file.

I was thinking about using the java.nio to validate the line before I process it. So, I was thinking of introducing a Validator trait as follows:

```
import java.nio.charset._
trait Validator{
   private def encoder = Charset.forName("UTF-8").newEncoder
   def isValidEncoding(line:String):Boolean = {
     encoder.canEncode(line)
   }
}
```

Do you guys think this is the correct approach to handle the situation?

Thanks

Comment: Well, does it work?  If yes, you're done!  If no (or "not good enough"), what went wrong?

Comment: @RexKerr - Ideally I would like to get the validator to make sure that the contents of the string conform to en-US. Still somewhat coming to terms with character encoding/decoding techniques, I was wondering if there were any tried and tested approaches that I could follow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is too late when you already have a `String`, UTF-8 can always encode any string*. You need to go to the point where you are decoding the file initially.

---

ISO-8859-1 is an encoding with interesting properties:

- Literally any byte sequence is valid ISO-8859-1
- The code point of each decoded character is exactly the same as the value of the byte it was decoded from

So you could decode the file as ISO-8859-1 and just strip non-English characters:

```
//Pseudo code
str = file.decode("ISO-8859-1");
str = str.replace( "[\u0000-\u0019\u007F-\u00FF]", "");
```

You can also iterate line-by-line, and ignore each line that contains a character in `[\u0000-\u0019\u007F-\u00FF]`, if that's what you mean by validating a line before processing it.

---

It also occurred to me that the binary marker could be a BOM. You can use a hex editor to view the values.

*Except those with illegal surrogates which is probably not the case here.

Answer (score 2):

Binary data is not a string. Don't try to hack around input sequences that would be illegal upon conversion to a `String`.

If your input is an arbitrary sequence of bytes (even if many of them conform to ASCII), don't even try to convert it to a `String`.